# Get access to all queues in Azure Storage Account

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am using Azure.Storage.Queues package as per the recommendation on Microsoft docs. I am connecting to queue using Queue Client something like below,

```
public class QueueClientSingleton : IQueueClientSingleton
{
    private readonly Lazy<QueueClient> _queueClientXyz;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public QueueClientSingleton(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

        _queueClientXyz = new Lazy<QueueClient>(() => new QueueClient(_configuration.ConnectionString, "QueueXyz");
    }
}
```

The above code is not tested but should work to provide access to QueueXyz. I have a use case wherein I want to connect to the storage account via connection string once and then

1. read thru different queues (pass queue name and get messages from that queue)
2. list all queues are present in that storage account

I found something like below but this is using the deprecated package: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage that we are not using in our solution. Is there something we can do using similarly with a new package: Azure.Storage.Queues

```
public static void CreateKnownAzureQueues(string azureConnectionString)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureConnectionString);
    CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

    foreach (var queueName in AzureQueues.KnownQueues)
    {
        queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName).CreateIfNotExists();
    }
}
```

Also, found below the link to request a list of all queues in the storage account. But, It does not provide any example as such.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-queues1#request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `Azure.Storage.Queues` package, you can use the code below to achieve your purpose:

```
        QueueServiceClient serviceClient = new QueueServiceClient(conn_str);
        
        //list all queues in the storage account
        var myqueues = serviceClient.GetQueues().AsPages();

        //then you can write code to list all the queue names          
        foreach (Azure.Page<QueueItem> queuePage in myqueues)
        {
            foreach (QueueItem q in queuePage.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q.Name);
            }

        }

        //get a queue client
        var myqueue_client = serviceClient.GetQueueClient("the queue name");
```

Comment: any idea of how to get queue clients for multiple queues? I know we can use serviceClient.GetQueueClient("the queue name") but then this will only be for one queue. how can we get queue clients for multiple queues at time? Basically I want to verify if there are any messages in QueueAbc, QueueXyz, QueuePQR, QueueLMN? Is the only option to loop for different queues?

Comment: @Vicky, for queueClient, you can only fetch it one by one.